# Why does 'emacs &' cause my program to crash - C?

Tags: c, shell, process, fork

last thing before I've finished finished my shell, can someone explain to me why when I run `emacs &` it causes my shell program to crash and mis-read the inputs for some reason. Below is my code for forking a new process to be run in the background, note, that the `&` in `emacs &` is removed from the command and tells my shell to run the command in the background. Many thanks in advance for any help or advice given.

```
int execBgCmd(char **cmds, Command cmd) {

  pid_t pid1, pid2;
  int status;

  if (pid1 = fork()) {
    waitpid(pid1, &status, 1);
  } else if (!pid1) {
    if (pid2 = fork()) {
      exit(0);
    } else if (!pid2) {
      if (cmd.rstdin != NULL) {
        int fd0 = open(cmd.rstdin, O_RDONLY);
        dup2(fd0, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd0);
      }
      if (cmd.rstdout != NULL) {
        int fd1 = open(cmd.rstdout , O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0644) ;
        dup2(fd1, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd1);
      }
      if (execvp(cmds[0], cmds) < 0) { 
        printf("\nCould not execute command, try again.\n"); 
      }

    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failure");
    }
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failure");
  }
  wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Yous should replace the `1` in `waitpid` with `WNOHANG` -- it's more portable and understandable.

Comment: `if (pid = /*...*/) else if (!pid) /*...*/ else /*...*/` has a redundant second `if` and the third branch is never taken. Please raise the warning level of your compiler to the max and clear all errors and warnings. And, please, provide a [example].

Comment: Does your parent program get killed or just hangs, `crash` isn't very helpful